# unable to change member value with method

Tags: c++

I have an int member named size within my blob class whose value I am attempting to change within a method.  Initially, I tried...

```
void blob::make_union(blob parent_blob){
    parent=&parent_blob;
    parent_blob.size = parent_size
}
```

Then I tried making a function whose sole purpose was to change the size value.  Its worth noting that it changes the values within the function as verified by some cout statements.

```
int blob::change_size(int dat_size){
    size=size+dat_size;
    return this.size;
}
```

after making the new method change my other method

```
'void blob::make_union(blob parent_blob){
    parent=&parent_blob;
    int temp = size;
    parent_blob.size = parent_blob.change_size(temp);
}'
```

still no dice.  The following within main function does work.

`if (charmatrix[m-1][n-1]==charmatrix[m][n]){
                blobmatrix[m][n].make_union(blobmatrix[m-1][n-1]);
                blobmatrix[m-1][n-1].size=blobmatrix[m-1][n-1].size + blobmatrix[m][n].size;`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `parent` ?  `parent_blob` is a local variable to the `make_union` function, so if you use `parent` after that function exits then you are in big trouble.

Comment: Also you should explain what you expected to happen, and what actually happened; of saying "no dice" or "unable to change". Nobody else knows what you thought should happen or even what your code was, since you also didn't include the code that produces the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: [See this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidelines on how to post code that "isn't working".

Comment: I was trying to err on the side of brevity.  Anyway, Tas below was able to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your `blob` class by value: you are making a copy of your `blob` object, and that is what the function `change_size` is working with.

```
void increment_number(int i) { ++i; }
void increment_number_ref(int& i) { ++i; }

int main()
{
    int n = 6;
    // This takes a copy of the number, and increments that number, not the one passed in!
    increment_number(n);
    // n == 6
    // This passed our object by reference. No copy is made, so the function works with the correct object.
    increment_number_ref(n);
    // n == 7
    return 0;
}
```

You need to pass your `blob` by reference (or as a pointer) if you wish to modify that object's value: see above.

Answer (score 0):

In languages that have pass by reference and pass by value - if you have a situation where you make a change, and then suddenly the change is 'gone', you're almost certainly passing a copy vs a reference.

Try changing the prototype to pass in the blob by reference.

Comment: @ninjaneer No problem. It can be tricky until you get the hang of it.