# Game// Can't change the values of overloaded constructor

Tags: c++, object, constructor-overloading

guys.
I'm tilted.
The problem is everytime a turn is made (my attack, enemy attack), both mine and enemy's statistics are reset. i.e Enemy has 20 HP, I deal 5 DMG, it detects the change and on the next print the enemy has 15 HP, but on the next turn it's HP is back to 20.(The same thing happens to the Hero Character.)
P.S Sorry for bad english and the bad written code really. Here is the whole code.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Hero
{
    string Name;
    int HP;
    int DMG;
    int LVL;
    int EXP;
    int MissChance;
    bool HeroCheck;
public:
    Hero(void);
    ~Hero(void);
    void Hero_Print();
    int BasicAttack();
    int HeavyAttack();
    void Heal();
    void LVLUP();
    int GetLVL();
    void SetHP(int NewHP);
    int GetHP();
    int GetMissChance();

};
#pragma once
#include "Hero.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

Hero::Hero(void)
{
    do{
    cout<<"TYPE YOUR HERO'S NAME:"<<endl;
    cin>>Name;
    }while(Name.length()>10);
    HP=20;
    DMG=5;
    LVL=1;
    EXP=0;
    MissChance=20;
    HeroCheck=true;
}


Hero::~Hero(void)
{
}

void Hero::Hero_Print()
{
    cout<<"____________"<<endl;
    cout<<Name<<"'s STATISTICS"<<endl;
    cout<<"HP: "<<HP<<endl;
    cout<<"DMG: "<<DMG<<endl;
    cout<<"LVL: "<<LVL<<endl;
    cout<<"EXP: "<<EXP<<endl;
    cout<<"____________"<<endl;
}

int Hero::BasicAttack()
{
    return DMG;
}
int Hero::HeavyAttack()
{
    return DMG+7;
}
void Hero::Heal()
{
    HP=HP+GetLVL();
}
void Hero::LVLUP()
{
    LVL++;
}
int Hero::GetLVL()
{
    return LVL;
}
void Hero::SetHP(int NewHP)
{
    HP=NewHP;
}
int Hero::GetHP()
{
    return HP;
}
int Hero::GetMissChance()
{
    return MissChance;
}

#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Enemy
{
    string Name;
    int HP;
    int DMG;
    int MissChance;
public:
    Enemy();
    void SetEnemy(string conName, int conHP, int conDMG, int conMissChance);
    ~Enemy(void);
    void Enemy_Print();
    int BasicAttack();
    int SpecialAttack();
    void Heal();
    int GetMissChance();
    void SetHP(int NewHP);
    int GetHP();
    string GetName();
};

#include "Enemy.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
Enemy::Enemy()
{
}
void Enemy::SetEnemy(string conName, int conHP, int conDMG, int conMissChance)
{
    Name=conName;
    HP=conHP;
    DMG=conDMG;
    MissChance=conMissChance;
}
Enemy::~Enemy(void)
{
}
void Enemy::Enemy_Print()
{
    cout<<"____________"<<endl;
    cout<<Name<<"'s Statistics"<<endl;
    cout<<"HP: "<<HP<<endl;
    cout<<"DMG: "<<DMG<<endl;
    cout<<"____________"<<endl;
}
int Enemy::BasicAttack()
{
    return DMG;
}
int Enemy::SpecialAttack()
{
    return DMG+3;
}
void Enemy::Heal()
{
    HP=HP+3;
}
void Enemy::SetHP(int NewHP)
{
    HP=NewHP;
}
int Enemy::GetHP()
{
    return HP;
}
int Enemy::GetMissChance()
{
    return MissChance;
}
string Enemy::GetName()
{
    return Name;
}

//All Battle Functions~~

void EnemyBattle(Hero Character, Enemy RandomEnemy);
void BasicAttack(Hero Character, Enemy RandomEnemy);
void SpecialAttack(Hero Character, Enemy RandomEnemy);
void HeroHeal(Hero Character);
void EnemyHeal(Enemy RandomEnemy);
int RandGen();
bool HPHero_Check(Hero Character);
bool HPEnemy_Check(Enemy RandomEnemy);
void Hero_Death(Hero Character);
void Enemy_Death(Enemy RandomEnemy);
void HeroAttacks_Couts(Hero Character);
int MakingTurn();
int MissChance();
void HeroBasicAttack(Hero Character, Enemy RandomEnemy);
void HeroHeavyAttack(Hero Character, Enemy RandomEnemy);
void HeroHeal(Hero Character);
void EnemyBasicAttack(Hero Character, Enemy RandomEnemy);
void EnemySpecialAttack(Hero Character, Enemy RandomEnemy);
void EnemyHeal(Enemy RandomEnemy);
void HeroTurn(Hero Character, Enemy RandomEnemy);
void EnemyTurn(Hero Character,Enemy RandomEnemy);
void SingleBattle(Hero Character,Enemy RandomEnemy);

#pragma once
#include "Enemy.h"
#include "Hero.h"
#include "Functions.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int MakingTurn()
{
    int TurnNum;
    do
    {
    cout<<"Make your turn: ";
    cin>>TurnNum;
    }while(TurnNum<0||TurnNum>3);
    system("cls");
    return TurnNum;
}

int MissChance()
{
    int RandomNum;
    srand (time(NULL));
    RandomNum = rand() % 100;
    return RandomNum;
}

int RandGen()
{
    int x;
    srand(time(NULL));
    x = rand()% 3+1;
    return x;
}

void HeroAttacks_Couts(Hero Character)
{
    cout<<"1.Basic Attack: "<<Character.BasicAttack()<<" DMG"<<endl;
    cout<<"2.Heavy Attack: "<<Character.HeavyAttack()<<" DMG"<<endl;
    cout<<"3.Heal yourself for "<<Character.GetLVL()*3<<" HP"<<endl;
}

#pragma once
#include "Enemy.h"
#include "Hero.h"
#include "Functions.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void Enemy_Death(Enemy RandomEnemy)
{
    system("cls");
    RandomEnemy.Enemy_Print();
    cout<<"You defeated the "<<RandomEnemy.GetName()<<"!"<<endl;
}

void Hero_Death(Hero Character)
{
    system("cls");
    Character.Hero_Print();
    cout<<"You died!"<<endl;
}

#pragma once
#include "Enemy.h"
#include "Hero.h"
#include "Functions.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool HPEnemy_Check(Enemy RandomEnemy)
{
    if(RandomEnemy.GetHP()<1)
    return false;
    else return true;
}

bool HPHero_Check(Hero Character)
{
    if(Character.GetHP()<1)
    return false;
    else return true;
}

#pragma once
#include "Enemy.h"
#include "Hero.h"
#include "Functions.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//My attacks

void HeroBasicAttack(Hero Character, Enemy RandomEnemy)
{
    if(Character.GetMissChance()<MissChance())
        {
            int NewHP=RandomEnemy.GetHP()-Character.BasicAttack();
            RandomEnemy.SetHP(NewHP);
            cout<<"Your attack was successful!"<<endl;
            RandomEnemy.Enemy_Print();
        }else cout<<"You missed your attack!"<<endl;
}
void HeroHeavyAttack(Hero Character, Enemy RandomEnemy)
{
    if(Character.GetMissChance()<MissChance())
        {
            int NewHP=RandomEnemy.GetHP()-Character.HeavyAttack();
            RandomEnemy.SetHP(NewHP);
            cout<<"Your attack was successful!"<<endl;
            RandomEnemy.Enemy_Print();
        }else cout<<"You missed your attack!"<<endl;
}
void HeroHeal(Hero Character)
{
    Character.Heal();
    cout<<"You successfully healed yourself!"<<endl;
    Character.Hero_Print();
}
//Enemy attacks
void EnemyBasicAttack(Hero Character, Enemy RandomEnemy)
{
    if(RandomEnemy.GetMissChance()<MissChance())
        {
            int NewHP=Character.GetHP()-RandomEnemy.BasicAttack();
            Character.SetHP(NewHP);
            cout<<"The "<<RandomEnemy.GetName()<<" hit you with his Basic Attack!"<<endl;
            Character.Hero_Print();
        }else cout<<"The "<<RandomEnemy.GetName()<<" missed you!"<<endl;
}
void EnemySpecialAttack(Hero Character,Enemy RandomEnemy)
{
    if(RandomEnemy.GetMissChance()<MissChance())
        {
            int NewHP=Character.GetHP()-RandomEnemy.SpecialAttack();
            Character.SetHP(NewHP);
        cout<<"The "<<RandomEnemy.GetName()<<" hit you with his Special Attack!"<<endl;
        Character.Hero_Print();
        }else cout<<"The "<<RandomEnemy.GetName()<<" missed you!"<<endl;
}
void EnemyHeal(Enemy RandomEnemy)
{
    RandomEnemy.Heal();
    cout<<"The "<<RandomEnemy.GetName()<<" successfully used Heal!"<<endl;
    RandomEnemy.Enemy_Print();
}

#include "Enemy.h"
#include "Hero.h"
#include "Functions.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void HeroTurn(Hero Character, Enemy RandomEnemy)
{
    switch(MakingTurn())
        {
            case 1:
                HeroBasicAttack(Character,RandomEnemy);
                break;
            case 2:
                HeroHeavyAttack(Character,RandomEnemy);
                break;
            case 3:
                HeroHeal(Character);
                break;
    }
}
void EnemyTurn(Hero Character, Enemy RandomEnemy)
{
    switch(RandGen())
        {
            case 1:
                EnemyBasicAttack(Character,RandomEnemy);
                break;
            case 2:
                EnemySpecialAttack(Character,RandomEnemy);
                break;
            case 3:
                EnemyHeal(RandomEnemy);
                break;
        }
}

#pragma once
#include "Enemy.h"
#include "Hero.h"
#include "Functions.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Both mine and enemy's turns
void SingleBattle(Hero Character,Enemy RandomEnemy)
{
    cout<<"You have encountered "<<RandomEnemy.GetName()<<"!Brace yourself for battle!"<<endl;
    RandomEnemy.Enemy_Print();
    do
        {
            if(!HPHero_Check(Character))
                {
                    Hero_Death(Character);
                    break;
                }else 
                    Character.Hero_Print();
                    HeroAttacks_Couts(Character);
                    HeroTurn(Character,RandomEnemy);
                    if(!HPEnemy_Check(RandomEnemy))
                        {
                            Enemy_Death(RandomEnemy);
                            break;
                        }else
                            EnemyTurn(Character,RandomEnemy);
                            RandomEnemy.Enemy_Print();
        }while(HPHero_Check(Character)||HPEnemy_Check(RandomEnemy));
}

#pragma once
#include "Enemy.h"
#include "Hero.h"
#include "Functions.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Selecting random enemy to fight
void EnemyBattle(Hero Character, Enemy RandomEnemy)
{
    switch(RandGen())
    {
    case 1:
        {
            RandomEnemy.SetEnemy("Orc",18,7,30);
            SingleBattle(Character,RandomEnemy);
            break;
        }
    case 2:
        {
            RandomEnemy.SetEnemy("Skeleton",15,9,35);
            SingleBattle(Character,RandomEnemy);
            break;
        }
    case 3:
        {
            RandomEnemy.SetEnemy("Ghost",17,4,20);
            SingleBattle(Character,RandomEnemy);
            break;
        }
    }
}



#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "Hero.h"
#include "Enemy.h"
#include "Functions.h"
using namespace std;
//Main
int main()
{
    Hero Character;
    Enemy RandomEnemy;
    bool GameRun = true;
    do
    {
    Character.Hero_Print();
    EnemyBattle(Character,RandomEnemy);
    }while( GameRun);

    return 0;
}
```

*

Comment: Please try extracting only the *relevant* code parts. That code is far too long.

Comment: Take the time to format your code or don't expect an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simply, you are passing your `Hero` and `Enemy` by copy. What this means is a COPY of your object is made, the damage/heal is applied to that, and this has no effect on the object you wish to modify.

See this question: [unable to change member value with method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29934320/unable-to-change-member-value-with-method/29934379#29934379)

```
int main()
{
    Hero Character;
    Character.Hero_Print();
    // This passes a COPY of the character. The heal is applied and then you print the copies stats
    HeroHeal(Character);
    // However, no changes have been made to Character.
    Character.Hero_Print();
}
```

## You need to pass your `Hero` by reference

```
// Takes a reference to the Hero
void HeroHeal(Hero& Character)
{
    Character.Heal();
    cout<<"You successfully healed yourself!"<<endl;
    Character.Hero_Print();
}
```

Now instead of passing a copy, a reference to the `Hero` is passed. Note that the way you call the function **does not change**. That is, you will still write this:

```
// Heal the actual hero (parameter passed by reference)
void HeroHeal(Hero& Character);
// Heal a clone of this hero (parameter passed by copy)
void HeroHealClone(Hero Clone);

int main()
{
    Hero newHero;
    HeroHeal(newHero);
    HeroHealClone(newHero);
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your time and help, it's really appreciated.

Comment: So, I did as you said, using references, but I got an Error : expecting an expression.
I changed the things like this

....
void HeroHeal(Hero& Character)
{
...
}

and I get the error in function HeroTurn() on this line

case 3:
HeroHeal(Character&);
break;

It underlines as error the last bracket before the ; P.S I really don't know how to format comments, sorry.

Comment: @r0shaff I updated my answer to include how to call a function when a parameter is passed as a reference (nothing changes to how its called when a copy is passed). If you are having further trouble, consider making your program as small as possible, and then slowly expand on it. It will definitely make solving issues easier, and will aid others if helping you if you need more help. If you continue to have problems, you may post a new question with a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which will help everyone help you.